# Nativescript/Js. How can I change the appearance of TabViewItem?

Tags: javascript, tabs, nativescript, tabview, nstabview

How do I change the appearance of TabViewItem ()?
I'm trying to set the radius of the border and the width of the border, as in the picture:

[image]

but it does not work:

```
var tabViewModule =  require("ui/tab-view");
    var tabEntry0 = new tabViewModule.TabViewItem();
        tabEntry0.borderRadius="30%";
        tabEntry0.borderWidth="30%";
```

Who know, how it doing.?