# Nativescript - TabView styling

Tags: nativescript, nstabview

I'm new on NativeScript, and I'm experimenting with differents templates that NS offers. I want to style and set "height", "border" and "radius" properties to each one of TabViewItem of a TabView.

I'm playing around fresh {N} Core JavaScript Tab template, created with:

```
tns create app-name --template tns-template-tab-navigation
```

The simplyfied code is:

```
<TabView selectedIndexChanged="onSelectedIndexChanged">
    <TabView.items>
        <TabViewItem title="Tab 1" iconSource="res://icon1">
           <TabViewItem.view>
                <!-- Content firts tab -->
           </TabViewItem.view>
       </TabViewItem>      

        <TabViewItem title="Tab 2" iconSource="res://icon2">
           <TabViewItem.view>
                <!-- Content second tab -->
           </TabViewItem.view>
       </TabViewItem>      
    </TabView.items>
</TabView>
```

I try to set height and borders inline, using style="", and too modifying css, but nothing works.

Properties like height and margin, works fine when applied to TabView, inline way, but don't work with TabViewItem.

Ideally, I would like to get something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369470/nativescript-js-how-can-i-change-the-appearance-of-tabviewitem) but as you can see, nobody has responded.